# Is there an alternative to document.getElementById to access dynamically generated elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I have a single page, forward button, back button and a Google map. When clicking forward or back buttons, I don't reload the page, I just change the HTML inside the following tag,

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

If a map is available, inside the "content" div will be,

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Google allows me to access the map with

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') ...
```

This works fine for the first time loading the page, but when I change the "content" dynamically, it won't load the map unless I reload the page. I tried changing it to document.querySelector() with the same results.

I know that for certain features like using buttons I can access them using,

```
$('body').on( 'change', 'div.button', function()...
```

Is there a way to access/modify a dynamically created element that isn't a button?

Comment: Are you instantiating a new `Map` object on the new element after changing the content? Please post enough of your code to let us reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which creates a new instance of the map is probably only running once. After you update the `#content` div, you need to run the code again to instantiate a new map (and, ideally, destroy the previous map).

How are you updating the content dynamically? If you're using `jQuery.get()` for example, you can supply a callback function which will run after the content has updated. It's here you'd want to load the map.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are absolutely correct. Completely forgot that I first have to create the new map before I can access it. I'll probably have to ask a new question because Google uses <script async defer src="https:/maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]&callback=initMap"></script> to access maps. Typically I would wrap something in a function and just call that function, but I have no idea how to initiate something already in a script.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery binds events to elements when the DOM is loaded. If you want to bind events to dynamically generated HTML, you'll either need to reinitialize the event or use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on a parent element that is not dynamically loaded. The example you used for [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is correct, but if you want to target something other than a button, just change `div.button` to any other selector. For instance:

```
$('#parent-div').on('event', '.selector', function() {
    // do something
});
```

This actually binds the event to `#parent-div`, but only listens when the `.selector` triggers the event.